# Bitmap size increases after compressing

Tags: android, bitmap

Here is a piece of code that I used to compress `Bitmap`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.out.println("before: " + bmp.getByteCount());
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
System.out.println("baos: "  + baos.toByteArray().length);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), 
           null, options);
System.out.println("after: " + b.getByteCount());
```

LogCat output:

```
12-29 11:45:52.638 18042-18042/com.xxx.yyy I/System.out: before: 653760
12-29 11:45:52.678 18042-18042/com.xxx.yyy I/System.out: baos: 13118
12-29 11:45:52.688 18042-18042/com.xxx.yyy I/System.out: after: 1307520
```

size of `baos` seems the size of `Bitmap` after compressing, but why `b.getByteCount()` return a larger size than `bmp` before compressing?

Comment: Try compressing with a smaller value for the `quaiity` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

 /*
   isSampleSize will reduce your bitmap size.
   If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save
   memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the
   decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original
   and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based
   on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.
 */
options.inSampleSize = 2; 
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new  ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), null, options);
System.out.println("after: " + b.getByteCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Same Problem but i solved using Some Method.i used this method in my Camera App after image Captured.i put my code here.Using it you will try.
My Methods :

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(Context context, byte[] bitmapBytes) {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    int reqWidth, reqHeight;
    Point point = new Point();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        display.getSize(point);
        reqWidth = point.x;
        reqHeight = point.y;
    } else {
        reqWidth = display.getWidth();
        reqHeight = display.getHeight();
    }

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inMutable = true;
    options.inBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Load & resize the image to be 1/inSampleSize dimensions
    // Use when you do not want to scale the image with a inSampleSize that is a power of 2
    options.inScaled = true;
    options.inDensity = options.outWidth;
    options.inTargetDensity = reqWidth * options.inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false; // If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.
    options.inPurgeable = true;         // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
    options.inInputShareable = true;    // Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    int initialInSampleSize = computeInitialSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    int roundedInSampleSize;
    if (initialInSampleSize <= 8) {
        roundedInSampleSize = 1;
        while (roundedInSampleSize < initialInSampleSize) {
            // Shift one bit to left
            roundedInSampleSize <<= 1;
        }
    } else {
        roundedInSampleSize = (initialInSampleSize + 7) / 8 * 8;
    }

    return roundedInSampleSize;
}

private static int computeInitialSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final double height = options.outHeight;
    final double width = options.outWidth;

    final long maxNumOfPixels = reqWidth * reqHeight;
    final int minSideLength = Math.min(reqHeight, reqWidth);

    int lowerBound = (maxNumOfPixels < 0) ? 1 :
            (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(width * height / maxNumOfPixels));
    int upperBound = (minSideLength < 0) ? 128 :
            (int) Math.min(Math.floor(width / minSideLength),
                    Math.floor(height / minSideLength));

    if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
        // return the larger one when there is no overlapping zone.
        return lowerBound;
    }

    if (maxNumOfPixels < 0 && minSideLength < 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (minSideLength < 0) {
        return lowerBound;
    } else {
        return upperBound;
    }
}
```

i think u need to Use My method  decodeSampledBitmapFromByte() instead of your 
method.you need to put all methods in your code.

Using this Code i get same size After compressing.i put my LogCat here.

[image: My Logcate]

Hope it will help You...Enjoy.(: